# web.config file is rendering the page when a partial url is correct

Tags: iis, web-config

We are having a peculiar issue.

There are a lot of products and categories on the site and we have a web.config file that redirects and rewrites the pages as per the category or product. All works good like when the page url for the category or the products is right , but when we add "anything" after the URL it does not give a page error or 404 not found, but it shows the last good page from the url.

for example:

https://websitename/sub-page/2w57w45uwas4jn

it still opens and shows the page as in

https://websitename/sub-page/

And it should go to a 404 page. The problem persists on all of these type of pages.

Another example:

https://websitename/sub-page/

can open with everything you write again after the "/"

https://websitename/sub-page/aetgashgwasegh

Any help here please as it is affecting our page ranking and SEO

The code for one url from the web.config file

```
<rule name="Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine/" />
<conditions>
<add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine/" /> 
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine.php" />
</rule>     

<rule name="Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine_rd" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine.php" />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="websitename/Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine.php" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="Z2-Auto-Travel-CPAP-Machine/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Both the rules are for the same product, the first rule is to rewrite the file to .php and the second rule is to redirect to the url

Comment: First please clear the cache and try again, if the same situation, please check if you have used url rewrite for rewriting.

Comment: hi, yes, I have used url_rewrite codes all over the web.config file

Comment: It may be caused by your url_rewrite codes, please post your url_rewrite codes.

Comment: sure , I have updated the question please have a look

Comment: Your url rule does not rewrite the url, but you can use failed request tracking to view detailed information.